# How to apply adapted conditional formatting to multiple rows?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a table with data, where I want to highlight the highest and lowest values in each row (using max() and min() built-ins with conditional formatting).
That works fine using an equals comparison with something like `max(B2:W2)`.
However when I want to apply the formatting to the subsequent rows (without having to enter and adjust the condition) again, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on LibreOffice 5.4.3.2: you can format all rows if first you select ColumnsA:W then Format > Conditional Formatting > Condition..., change to **Formula is** and apply:

```
A1=max($A1:$W1)
```

with Accent of your choice, then Add and repeat with a different Accent and:

```
A1=min($A1:$W1)
```

followed by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>.

This will favour the maximum format where a row contains only one value (even if repeated).

Accents may be suppressed for empty rows with an addition to each formula of an AND condition, thus for maximum, for example:

```
AND(A1=MAX($A1:$W1),A1<>"")
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `A1=max($B1:$W1)`, or preferably `X1=max($B1:$W1)` if `A1` has a value already?